# sed command to reverse all two digit numbers in a string of numbers

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to find all two number digits only in the following list and reverse only those - I have tried the code below but it is also reversing the first two digits of the 123 number also - How do I get it to ignore the 123 number and just reverse the two digit numbers

```
echo "87 123 45 6"  | sed -re 's/([0-9])([0-9])/\2\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed, use this:

```
sed -e 's/\<\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\>/\2\1/g'
```

The `\<` indicates the beginning of a word, `\>` the end.

Comment: @Jaypal It does nothing for 3 digit numbers, *as specified in the question.*

Comment: Hi Michael, just what I was looking for - im new to this and you exaplined it perfectly for me - Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try this would work
 echo "87 123 45 6" | sed -re 's/ ([0-9])([0-9]) / \2\1 /g'
here I add space and this fix the problem.

Comment: That won't change the first number, as it is not preceded by a space. If the last number had two digits, it would fail there, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include word boundary markers:

```
$ echo "87 123 45 6" | sed -re 's/\b([0-9])([0-9])\b/\2\1/g'
78 123 54 6
```

Voila!